# show entered new password in unix "passwd" command

Tags: command-line, password, passwd

Is is possible to run the **passwd** command with an option to show the newly entered passwords? By default it doesn't show what I type and I don't want this.

```
[dave@hal9000 ~]$ passwd 
Changing password for user dave.
Changing password for dave.
(current) UNIX password: 
New password: bowman
Retype new password: bowman
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

Comment: You mean you want to see a password someone entered? If so...no.

Comment: I think OP is asking how to enable input echo at the "Enter new UNIX password" prompts.  Maybe?

Comment: @jscott right, thats what I mean

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? This is not a good idea

Comment: Just wanted to use this in a local virtual machine, where security is not really a concern

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to go this path and there's no **passwd** parameter, you can use this [Expect](http://expect.nist.gov/) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect -f
set old_timeout $timeout
set timeout -1

stty -echo
send_user "Current password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set old_password $expect_out(1,string)

stty echo
send_user "\nNew password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
set new_password $expect_out(1,string)

set timeout $old_timeout
spawn passwd
expect "password:"
send "$old_password\r"
expect "password:"
send "$new_password\r"
expect "password:"
send "$new_password\r"
expect eof
```

How it works:

```
[dave@hal9000 ~]$ ./passwd.tcl
Current password: 
New password: bowman
spawn passwd
Changing password for user dave.
Changing password for dave.
(current) UNIX password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

---

This shell script might also work (tested on Fedora 20 with bash-4.2.47-2 and passwd-0.79-2):

```
#!/bin/sh
stty -echo
echo -n "Current password: "
read old_password

stty echo
echo
echo -n "New password: "
read new_password

passwd << EOF
$old_password
$new_password
$new_password
EOF
```

How it works:

```
[dave@hal9000 ~]$ ./passwd.sh
Current password: 
New password: bowman
Changing password for user dave.
Changing password for dave.
(current) UNIX password: New password: Retype new password: passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not completely clear on what exactly you are trying to see...your own password? Someone else's?

As I recall even the OS doesn't really know your password because it's hashed. You can clear a password from the shadow file, effectively blanking it (by booting from another boot disk, usually) then re-enter the password, but snatching the actual password would entail cracking the hashed string...brute forcing it or using a dictionary attack, rainbow tables or something like that. I'll leave the mechanics to your Google-fu.

So in short; no, you can't retrieve the password without intercepting and recording keystrokes, but you can erase the password if you have physical access to the drive (or image).

EDIT: Ah, clarified to show what you're typing as you type it. Again, nope, not in any version I know of. I believe this is to prevent shoulder surfing; people looking over your shoulder as you type, or remotely viewing your display as you type.

If you want to work around it (if you're using a GUI, for example) you can cut and paste your text string into the prompt, although that would usually be a pain. It depends on why you are wishing to echo your text (why bother double entering the password if you can see what you're typing...that was the point to having you re-enter your password, to cut down on typos.)

Depending on how your version of Linux works I suppose you could try directly hashing a password string and entering that resulting hash into the shadow file...kind of a strange workaround but one that may work. Or you could find an odd workaround wherein you have a PAM module authenticate against a different system/database that you can alter more directly. But anything that reveals your password at some stage through plain text is kind of asking for trouble from a security standpoint...you would need to decide how much risk you're willing to take.